# Why does passing a vector work but not a slice?

Tags: rust, slice, borrow-checker

When I write this:

```
fn add1(vc: &mut Vec<usize>) {
    func1(vc, vc[0]);
}
fn func1(vc: &mut Vec<usize>, val: usize) {}
```

Clippy tells me that "writing `&mut Vec` instead of `&mut [_]` involves a new object where a slice will do".

However if I switch it to this:

```
fn add1(vc: &mut Vec<usize>) {
    func1(vc, vc[0]);
}
fn func1(vc: &mut [usize], val: usize) {}
```

I get "cannot borrow `*vc` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable [E0502]".

This makes sense, but why then did it work before?

Also, why is Clippy giving me incorrect warnings?

[Link to working example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=afb1704ebdbf2c69be07dd7f027ce8cd)

[Link to not working example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c1bf5aa7d8cd68220c0ae7ac8160c8b0)

Comment: The difference is possibly because the coercion from `&mut Vec<usize>` to `&mut [usize]` involves a reborrow, whereas in the first example there is no coercion.

Comment: @kaya3 why would that make any difference?

Comment: You can convert _both_ functions to take a slice: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=df126deeb71a3e2d2ef7f4bf8ecf8ba3

Comment: You can also call `as_mut()` to create an explicit `&mut [usize]` and use it for both arguments, which compiles: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e39a8429394f342982e8a74d81f5ffda

Comment: @user4815162342 "You can convert both functions to take a slice"

In this example yes, but I'm more interested in why it's not working rather than how to fix it (rearranging the args also works in this example)

Comment: The first (working) example triggers an implicit reborrow of `vc`, which apparently somehow happens _after_ processing the whole parameter list. The second (non-working) example triggers an unsized coercion, which apparently happens at the time the first parameter is encountered. This timing means that in the first case, `vc` is not borrowed yet when the second argument is processed, while in the second case it is. _Why_ the timing is like this, I have no idea, and there is no documentation about it.

Comment: order mater https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=67febe79366882f3dcb395073714f854, I don't even see how the first version compile but anyway

Comment: @Stargateur I mentioned that in my earlier comment, my question is about why it's happening rather than how to fix it